# What do subscripts mean?

Tags: general-topology

"For $c∈R∖ \{x\}$, simply choose $ϵ=|x−c|$ and note that $x∉B_ϵ(c)$."

Specifically, I would like to know what $B_ϵ(c)$ means.

Answer (score 3):

$B_\varepsilon(c)$ should be the open ball of center $c$ and radius $\varepsilon$. However, this is not the only viable notation. Others may use $B(c,\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Ohh okay, thank you! :)